# Writing my own logs in db2diag

Tags: logging, db2

I would like to know if it is possible to write into the db2 diagnostic facility db2diag.

For example, I have a stored procedure, and I would like to write something in that file.

Is there any API to access to this facility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write directly in the db2diag.log file, it is necessary to use the DB2 API, specifically the db2AdminMsgWrite file. The log will indicate that this is a user log, with all the components of a normal db2 log.